# Flyback transformer simulation in LTspice

Tags: power-supply, transformer, power-electronics, flyback

I am trying to simulate a flyback transformer in LTspice having an input voltage of Vin = 12 V, turns ratio = 8.45, coupling coefficient = 0.8. As per the calculation, output voltage should become vout = 81.1 V, but its is only 70 V. Primary inductances are taken as L1 and L2 = 0.15 mH and 10.8 mH respectively. What could be the possible issues in the circuit?

[image]

Comment: That's a terrible coupling coefficient. There are plenty of things wrong here with your schematic.

Comment: *How* did you calculate it? Maybe that's where the error is. Remember, [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigo). If an ideal test case for a flyback topology is what you need then you're better off using [ideal elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbQxq.png), which can be taylored to have minimal losses. Otherwise, the bare `NPN` will likely not have the required characteristics (see the help under *LTspice > Circuit Elements > Q. ...*); similar for the diode.

Answer (score 1):

With 70V appearing on the secondary with a 1kΩ load, that is 4.9W of power. Assuming 100% efficiency across the transformer, that is 4.9W on the primary from 12V, which means an average of 400mA. When you consider ~0.6V in the rectifying diode, you are losing ~1.5V on the primary side.

1. winding resistors - it appears this is presently 0Ω
2. BJT conduction losses - it is not stated the type of BJT
3. BJT slow switching - it is not stated the type of BJT

if you plot the Collector voltage you should see what is being dropped on the primary side. Also consider a FET

Answer (score 0):

You need a snubber across the primary of your flyback xfmr. It does not show the breakdown voltage of the generic npn but it's probably being exceeded. For initial simulations set the coupling factor to 1. You can put a more realistic value in when you have ironed out the other bugs. Your npn needs a series limiting resistor. Probably better to go with an n-channel mosfet. Snubber still applies.
The voltage spike on the collector/drain can get pretty high. Remember the output voltage is a factor of duty cycle and turns ratio.
Put actual components in not the generic. Then at least it's easier to pinpoint issues.